# Inlining jQuery datetimepicker in ASP.NET MVC2 partial view

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

How do I make the jQuery datetimepicker appear inline in the following partial view ?  What I get now is a textbox that brings up the datetimepicker when it is clicked.  I want datetimepicker inline instead of textbox.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AkwiMemorial.Models.DateActionModel>" %>
<link href="../../Content/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Date').datepicker({ inline: true });     
    });
</script>


 <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>  
    <div>
       <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Date)%>
    </div>
     <input type="submit" value="OK" />

    <% } %>
```

the model is as follows:

```
public class DateActionModel
    {
        public DateActionModel() { Date = DateTime.UtcNow; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't the [inline demo for Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline) do what you want, along with the `onSelect` event?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
          $('#Date').val(dateText);
        }
      });     
    });
</script>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>  
<div>
   <div id="datepicker"><%= model.Date %></div>
   <%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Date)%>
</div>
 <input type="submit" value="OK" />

<% } %>
```

---

EDIT:

More explanation about the code.

To display inline, you need a `<div>`element instead of a text box, hence `<div id="datepicker">`. By doing this, `Date` is no longer a form field, so a hidden field was added for this, i.e. `Html.HiddenFor`. Then the `onSelect` option is used to observe changes made to the calendar, and update the hidden field accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I have no clue what the above snippet does but I am seeing an inline datepicker.  Just need to sort out some layout issues now.  Thanks again.

Comment: One more question, if I may, what is this supposed to do: